# Convert .sh file to .bat

Tags: bash, batch-file

Is it possible to convert the following .sh file to .bat for it to operate in a DOS environment without any add-ons such as cygwin64. My issue is that i cannot find an equivalent DOS command for the BASH command gcc.

```
cd hbc/models
gcc -O3 labels.c stats.c samplib.c LabeledLDA_infer_stdin.c -o LabeledLDA_infer_stdin.out -lm
cd ../../
tar xvzf TinySVM-0.09.tar.gz
cd TinySVM-0.09
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/../ && make && make install
cd ../python/cap
bash build.sh
```

Comment: gcc is not bash command; it is the GNU C compiler. You will need to install some C compiler (eg.: gcc or Microsoft Visual Studio's internal C compiler), and have the program on your PATH.

Comment: `configure` and `build.sh` will have `bash` commands.

Comment: You don't just have a single script to convert; you have an entire tool chain to install.

Answer (score 0):

gcc is not a bash command, but a c compiler. You should download a MinGW and set path to a bin folder. And then you'll be able to use a gcc command in a batch script.